# Is it correct that systemd timer AccuracySec parameter make the ticks slip?

Tags: timer, cron, systemd

I have the sad impression that the timer ticks are slipping by the amount of `AccuracySec`.

I am used to CRON, and with something like "*/5 * * * ...", it would run every 5 minutes (although it would not restart the process if still running, exactly what I needed.)

The CRON schedule could be defined as:

```
...--|-----|-----|--...--->
    :05   :10   :15
```

Now I convert that to `systemd` with a file that looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run the snapbackend service once every 5 minutes.

[Timer]
OnUnitActiveSec=5min

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

So I still want to get a tick every 5 minutes.

However, they have this parameter named `AccuracySec` and by default is set to 1 minute. As you can see, I do not set it because it says:

> This is done in order to optimize power consumption to suppress unnecessary CPU wake-ups.

But it looks like they *synchronize* timers together rather than start the new task *on time*. Not only that, the way it is implemented, the `AccuracySec` seems cumulative. It looks like this happens:

```
...--|-----+-|-----+-|-----+-|--...
    :05     :11     :17     :23
```

The `+` represents the time when the timer times out, and the `|` represents the time when the timed service gets executed.

It looks to me that the 1 minute delay means that the next timer will happen 2 minutes "late" instead of just one. As shown on my schedule, for a `systemd` timer, ticks happen at :05, :11, :17, :23. What I was expecting was: :05, :10, :15, :20, etc... (Note that if the first tick hits at :05, then the timer was schedule for :04 and waited 1 minute to not wake up the CPU too soon. Then it would compute the next tick at :09 but execute it only at :10, etc.)

Am I correct that the timers are slipping?

Answer (score 5):

Quick Answer: Yes. It slips. (Note: this is in Ubuntu 16.04, maybe it will get fixed in later versions of systemd...)

### Test

As proposed by [@MarkStosberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/254318/mark-stosberg) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176514/is-it-correct-that-systemd-timer-accuracysec-parameter-make-the-ticks-slip/39212100#39212100), I created a timer with no `Accuracy` variable, so as to use the default of 1 minute and then added the variable to test with 1 second to see whether my time would slip.

#### The 3 files I setup for my test

**snaptest.timer**

First I created a file named `snaptest.timer` without the `AccuracySec` parameter:

```
[Unit]
Description=Test the slipping timer...
[Timer]
OnUnitActiveSec=5min
[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

For the second test, I added the `AccuracySec` parameter and set it to 1 (which means 1 second):

```
[Unit]
Description=Test the slipping timer...
[Timer]
OnUnitActiveSec=5min
AccuracySec=1           <-- added this for 2nd test
[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

**snaptest.service**

Second I created a file named `snaptest.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Test slippage by logging messages
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/snaptest
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**/usr/bin/snaptest**

Third I created a script named `/usr/bin/snaptest`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo `date` >>/var/log/snapwebsites/snaptest.log
```

A very simple script indeed giving me results in a file named `snaptest.log`.

#### Starting the Timer

For those who do not know, to start the timer, you just need to do a start as in:

```
systemctl start snaptest.timer
```

In this case, you must specify the ".timer".

Also, that won't be enough because the `snaptest.service` never ran and the timer does not start unless the service runs at least once. So the first run requires a kick:

```
systemctl start snaptest
```

#### Test Results

The first set presents the results with the default of 1 minute accuracy:

```
Mon Aug 29 14:34:07 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 14:39:09 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 14:44:37 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 14:50:09 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 14:56:09 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 15:02:09 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 15:08:09 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 15:14:09 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 15:20:09 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 15:26:09 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 15:32:09 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 15:38:09 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 15:44:09 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 15:50:09 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 15:56:09 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 16:02:09 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 16:08:09 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 16:14:09 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 16:20:09 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 16:26:09 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 16:32:09 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 16:38:09 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 16:44:09 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 16:50:09 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 16:56:09 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 17:02:09 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 17:08:09 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 17:14:09 PDT 2016
```

The second set of results show the results with an accuracy of 1 second:

```
Mon Aug 29 17:19:57 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 17:24:57 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 17:29:58 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 17:34:59 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 17:40:00 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 17:45:01 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 17:50:02 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 17:55:03 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 18:00:04 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 18:05:05 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 18:10:06 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 18:15:07 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 18:20:08 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 18:25:09 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 18:30:10 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 18:35:11 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 18:40:12 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 18:45:13 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 18:50:14 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 18:55:15 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 19:00:16 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 19:05:17 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 19:10:18 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 19:15:19 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 19:20:20 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 19:25:21 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 19:30:22 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 19:35:23 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 19:40:24 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 19:45:25 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 19:50:26 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 19:55:27 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 20:00:28 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 20:05:29 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 20:10:30 PDT 2016
Mon Aug 29 20:15:31 PDT 2016
```

### My take on these results

Obviously, it slips... By a window of time that varies between 0 and `AccuracySec`.

I suppose that if I want to avoid the slippage, I have to use the `OnCalendar` option instead.

Comment: Your test was for maximum accuracy used "1 second" for the accuracy. What is recommended in the docs and in my answer is "1us", which is the maximum accuracy. I recommend re-running your test with that. If it still slips, report a bug.

Comment: Although, your result of "every 5 minutes with 1 second accuracy" already looks like a bug, as all the entries are are spaced 00:05:01 apart, not an average of 00:05:00 as expected.

Comment: @MarkStosberg Exactly, it looks like the window of time that the accuracy defines is cumulative. If you think that is a bug, I'll be happy to file it as such wherever systemd takes such (github maybe?) Of course, with accuracy of "1us", it would probably take much longer to notice the slip...

Comment: You are right that if an accuracy of "1 second"  slips 1 second per cycle, we can reason that an accuracy of "1us" slips "1us" per cycle. You can search and file bugs here: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues Also check the Changelog/History file to see if there's mention of this getting fixed in a version newer than yours.

Comment: @MarkStosberg, lets see what happens... https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/4083 — and thank you for the link!

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the docs for systemd.timers](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html#OnActiveSec=), the timers are not slipping. The timers are running "once every 5 minutes", but the execution time during each 5 minute window is randomized. That's often desirable behavior in a cluster when you don't want a "stampede" of activity at particular intervals, but want to even out the load of background services.

As the docs say,

> *To get best accuracy, set [AccuracySecs] to 1us .*

Check for yourself by creating a dummy service that simply writes to a log file or the journal every 5 minutes, and let it run for half an hour. Try it with and without `AccuracySecs=1us`.

I expect both runs will produce one-run-every-5-minutes, with `AccuracySecs=1us` producing runs exactly every 5 minutes.

Comment: I thought running a test, as you pointed out, would be an excellent idea. So I created a few files, very simple (with the minimum to get things to work) and waited a bit and... in my results, I can see the slippage. Unfortunately.